# Download file and open it without saving it in downloads folder

Tags: asp.net, http, download, .net-5

We try to download a file from the web server (.NET 5 / MVC) and open it automatically on the client side with the specific appliation without saving the file on the local disk. In our case we download a CAD file (*.dwg) and open it with DWG TrueView.

The file gets downloaded and application will be started as well. But every time we click on a file in out web application, the browser save a copy of the file in the downloads folder.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem?
Citrix does the same with ICA files - once I tell the browser it should open ICA files, it will not save the files on the disk.

This is roughly how the code looks like:

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadFile()
{
  var fs = new FileStream("myFilePath....", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  return new File(fs,"application/octet-stream","myFile.dwg");
}
```

We also tried all sorts of content-types without success.

Comment: You cannot control what the user will do with the downloaded file.

Comment: I know - but what about PDF documents that will be opened in the browser without beeing stored in the download folder (e.g. E-banking) or Cirtix ICA files I mentioned in my question?

Comment: @Skuami that file *is* stored in disk folder. It may be a temporary folder, but it's still a disk folder. What you describe is the `inline` behavior of the [content-disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header. Even with the `inline` header the browser has to know how to handle that file. You're sending it as an `octet-stream` which means the browser has no idea what that file contains

Comment: Try changing the content type to `image/x-dwg`.